# make dictionary from csv file columns

Tags: python

i am new to the concept of dictionaries in python.
I have a csv file with multiple columns and i want to create a dictionary such that keys are taken from 1st column and values from the second and a key:value pair is made for all rows of those two columns. 
The code is as follows:

```
    if __name__=="__main__":
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
for rows in reader:
        k = rows[0]
        v = rows[1]
        mydict = {k:v}
print (mydict)
```

problem: The output returned is only for "last" or "bottom most" row of the first two columns i.e. {'12654':'18790'}. i want the dictionary to contain all 100 rows of the first two columns in this format. How to do that? can i run some loop on the row numbers for the first two columns to do that...i dont know how.

Comment: Do you mean that the keys are taken from the first _row_?

Comment: here the code takes keys from the last row (two cols of last row) but i want it to go in sequence from 1st to last covering two cols of every row of my file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    mydict = {}
    reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
    for rows in reader:
        k = rows[0]
        v = rows[1]
        mydict[k] = v
    print mydict
```

Here:

```
mydict = {k:v}
```

You were making new dictionary in every iteration, and the previous data has been lost.

Update:

You can make something like this:

```
mydict = {}
L = [(1, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)]
for el in L:
    k, v = el
    if not k in mydict:
        mydict[k] = [v]
    else:
        mydict[k].append(v)

print mydict

>>> 
{1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [2, 4]}
```

This way, each value of the same key will be stored

Your code will be:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    mydict = {}
    reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
    for i, rows in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0: continue
        k = rows[0]
        v = rows[1]
        if not k in mydict:
            mydict[k] = [v]
        else:
            mydict[k].append(v)

    print mydict
```

Update2: You mean?

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    print "%s: %s" % (k, v)

>>>
1: [2, 3]
2: [4]
3: [2, 4]
```

Update3:

This should work:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
        mydict = {}
        reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
        for i, rows in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0: continue
            k = rows[0]
            v = rows[1]
            if not k in mydict:
                mydict[k] = [v]
            else:
                mydict[k].append(v)

        print mydict
```

Comment: Both codes work but partially solve the problem because the key:value pairs in dictionary are not in order for all rows i.e row 1, 2,3 etc. rather they are randomly made and do not include all 100 rows. is it because many key values in column are being repeated? and keys have to be unique in a dictionary?

Comment: in both columns of my data...values are being repeated. like if row 8 has 12345:90873 then row 48 can have 90873:12345. And in other rows the pairing of 12345 is different like 12345:87632 and similarly for 90873:76004.

Comment: thanks alot..this does list all values for key 12345 where 12345 is in 1st column n all corresponding values in col2 for 12345 in col 1 are stored in dict.

Comment: Another thing here...if i want to print each {key:[value,value]} separately i.e. list each key:values combo in one line and the next key:values in another and so on being in the same dictionary...can i separate contents in a dictionary this way?

Comment: or simply cant i have it row-wise?....for row1: key1:value1, for row2: key2:value2 and so on...even if some keys are repeated in col1 with distinct 'values' or the key in one col1 is 'value' in col2 for other 'keys'.i really hope its makin sense...

Comment: update 2 works good! :) Here i have given a heading to each column too which is in first row of both columns. That gets printed in the dictionary too:S can that 1st heading row be skipped and dict be made from 2nd line of file on wards uptil the end?

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new dict and overwriting the old one each iteration. [@develerx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353743/make-dictionary-from-csv-file-columns/7353760#7353760) fixes this problem. I just wanted to point an easier way, using dict comprehensions:

Assuming the csv file contains two columns.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))
    my_dict = {k: v for k, v in reader}
    print mydict
```

If you are using older version(older than 2.7 I think), you can't use dict comprehensions, just use the dict function then:

```
my_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in reader)
```

Edit: And I just thought that; `my_dict = dict(reader)` could also work.

Comment: You can use the second or third one.