# Python-How can i change part of a row in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with some words in, followed by a number and need a way to append the number; either adding 1 to it, or setting it back to 1.
Say for instance I have these words:

```
variant,1
sixty,2
game,3
library,1
```

If the user inputs the number sixty, how could I use that to add one onto the number, and how would I reset it back to 1?

I've been all over Google+Stackoverflow trying to find an answer, but I expect me not being able to find an answer was due more to my inexperience than anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick throw together using fileinput.  Since I am unaware of the conditions for why you would decrease or reset your value, I added it in as an keyword arg you can pass at will.  Such as

```
updateFileName(filename, "sixty", reset=True)
updateFileName(filename, "sixty", decrease=True)
updateFileName(filename, "sixty")
```

The results of each should be self-explanatory.  Good luck!  I wrapped it in a Try as I had no clue how your structure was, which will cause it to fail ultimately either way.  If you have spaces you will need to .strip() the key and value.

```
import fileinput
def updateFileName(filename, input_value, decrease=False, reset=False):
    try:
        for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
            key, value = line.split(",")
            if key == input_value:
                if decrease:
                    sys.stdout.write("%s,%s"(key, int(value) - 1)
                elif reset:
                    sys.stdout.write("%s,%s"(key, 1)
                else:
                    sys.stdout.write("%s,%s"(key, int(value) + 1)
                continue
            sys.stdout.write(line)

    finally:
        fileinput.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing when you want to switch a number to 1 and when you want to add 1, I can't give a full answer, but I can set you on the right track. 
First you want to import the csv file, so you can change it around. 
The csv module is very helpful in this. Read about it here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

You will likely want to read it into a dictionary structure, because this will link each word to it's corresponding number.  Something like this [make dictionary from csv file columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353743/make-dictionary-from-csv-file-columns?rq=1)

Then you'll want to use raw_input (or input if you are using Python 3.0)
to get the word you are looking for and use that as the key to find and change the number you want to change. http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/handsonHtml/handson.html#x1-490001.12
or http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/
will show you how to get one part of a dictionary by giving it the other part and how to save info back into a dictionary.

Sorry it's not a direct answer. Maybe someone else will write one up, but it should get you started,

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick and informative response, I will look into using dictionaries. I want to add 1 to the number when the user enters the correct answer, and reset the number back to 1 when they get it wrong. I already have a function that determines whether or not they got the answer right, and returns a True/False bool. I was going to use this to either add 1 to the number or reset it back to 1, basically showing how many times in a row they got this word right.

Answer (score 0):

This is very probably not the best way to do it but you can load your csv file in an array object using numpy with the help of [loadtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).
The following code is going to give you a 2 dimension array with names in the first column and your numbers in the second one.

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.loadtxt('YourFile',delimiter=',')
```

Perform your changes on the numbers the way you want and use the numpy [savetxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html?highlight=savetxt#numpy.savetxt) to save your file.
If your file is very heay, this solution is going to be a pain as loading a huge array takes a lot of memory. So consider it just as a workaround. The dictionary solution is actually better (I think).